# Error script Bash FTP

Tags: bash

Saludos tengo un script que me permite subir un archivo comprimido a una carpeta especifica de FTP, el mismo funcionaba bien, pero ahora me genera el siguiente error:

> 0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ftp.miservidor.com; Error
>   desconocido

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#!/bin/bash
####################################
#
# Backup directory
# se crea para automatizar respaldos
# Creado por: Diego Loachamin
# Fecha: 2018-09-14
#
####################################
#fecha
day=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M")

#directorio a respaldar
directory="/mi/directorio/a/respaldar"

#destino backup
archive_file="backupCodigo_$day.tgz"

destino="/var/backups/$archive_file"
tar -cvpzf $destino $directory

# CredencialesFTP (se puede especificar el puerto. ftp.ejemplo.com:2002)
ftpUser=miusuario@miservidor.com
ftpPass=miclave123
ftpHost=ftp.miservidor.com:21
ftpFolder="micarpetaDestino/"

echo "SuBiEnDo ArChIvO: $file Al SeRvIdOr"
curl --ftp-create-dirs -T $destino -u $ftpUser:$ftpPass ftp://$ftpHost/$ftpFolder
```

sin embargo para descartar que este mal la dirección, puerto o credenciales use Filezilla con los datos en cuestión y funciona perfecto.

Comment: el ordenador donde tienes ese script debe tener configurado un dns. Sabes si ese dns es capaz de resolver de forma correcta el host que indicas? para ello prueba a hacer un `dig ftp.miservidor.com` y comprueba que la entrada ftp apunta correctamente. Hay algunos operadores que no actualizan correctamente sus dns y puede que no te este redirigiendo bien (prueba a configurar el `0.0.0.0` en caso de que no resuelva correctamente.

Comment: El problema dice claramente que no puede resolver el nombre. O es un fallo del DNS o de la configuración dns del host, pero no relacionado al _script_.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos en si la solución fue algo simple con tan solo agregar comillas a cada una de las credenciales es decir de esto:

```
ftpUser=miusuario@miservidor.com
ftpPass=miclave123
```

pasamos a esto:

```
ftpUser="miusuario@miservidor.com"
ftpPass="miclave123"
..
```

Espero le sirva a alguien mas , lo mas curioso fue que funcionaba sin comillas y de un tiempo acá me dio dicho error.